# Groovy Spock mock calling real method of mocked class

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock, vision-api

I am trying to write a unit test for a class that uses Google's vision API with the `AnnotatorImageClient` from the `google-cloud-vision` lib.
The problem is that my mocked `AnnotatorImageClient` for some reason still calls the real `batchAnnotateImages` method and then throws a NPE, which breaks my test. 
I have never seen this behavior on a mock before and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, if there is a bug in spock/groovy or if it has something to do with that Google lib?

I have already checked if the object used in my class is really a mock, which it is. I have tried with Spock version 1.2-groovy-2.5 and 1.3-groovy.2.5

The class that is tested:

```
public class VisionClient {

    private final ImageAnnotatorClient client;

    @Autowired
    public VisionClient(final ImageAnnotatorClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Optional<BatchAnnotateImagesResponse> getLabelsForImage(final Image image) {
        var feature = Feature.newBuilder().setType(LABEL_DETECTION).build();

        var request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                .addFeatures(feature)
                .setImage(image)
                .build();

        return Optional.ofNullable(client.batchAnnotateImages(singletonList(request)));
}
```

The test:

```
class VisionClientSpec extends Specification {
    def "The client should use Google's client to call Vision API"() {
        given:
        def googleClientMock = Mock(ImageAnnotatorClient)
        def visionClient = new VisionClient(googleClientMock)
        def imageMock = Image.newBuilder().build()

        when:
        def resultOpt = visionClient.getLabelsForImage(imageMock)

        then:
        1 * googleClientMock.batchAnnotateImages(_ as List) >> null
        !resultOpt.isPresent()
    }
}
```

I would expect the mock to simply return `null` (I know that this test doesn't make a lot of sense). Instead, it calls `com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.batchAnnotateImages` which throws an NPE.

Comment: Try with just `_` - it seems that the parameter `_ as List` is not matched correctly?

Comment: I tried it with ```_``` too, but it still gets me the same result. Even when I ommit the stubbing completely, the result is still the same: real method gets called, NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `ImageAnnotatorClient` is written in Java, and method `batchAnnotateImages(List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests)` is `final`.

Spock is able to mock Java final classes, but not such good in mocking Java final methods.

You can use [PowerMock](https://powermock.github.io/) to get what you need, [here](https://medium.com/@WZNote/how-to-make-spock-and-powermock-work-together-a1889e9c5692) is tutorial how to get it work together with Spock.

Comment: But one could change the modifier [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822216/1087447)

Comment: @Jazzschmidt yes you're right, reflection is a second option to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction! It really seems that groovy has a problem with classes that are themselves not final but contain final methods. I solved the issue by creating a little facade between my class and the ```ImageAnnotatorClient``` that just serves as a proxy and can be mocked by Spock without problems.

Comment: I had a problem like this in Kotlin, because the method was not marked with keyword "open". This response gave me the correct clue :)

So keep an eye out for this in case you are using kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to annotate the mocked field with `SpringBean` with this import;

`import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean`