# Spock Mock String value in class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I'm using Spring and I want to create unit test using Spock. This is my class

```
@Service
public class TestService{
    @Value("${test.path:}")
   private String path;
}
```

Is it any way to mock this variable in Spock tests without runing spring context?

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you just set the value on the `properties` parameter of `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: But I don't want to use spring context

Comment: I see! That's a very important thing to mention in your question

Comment: The only way I see it working is by using reflection, I'm not a heavy user of Spock. This can possible help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552600/using-spock-to-mock-private-static-final-variables-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you don't want to set up a Spring(Boot) test, either inject the value field using constructor injection:

```java
@Service
public class TestService{
   private String path;

   public TestService(@Value("${test.path:}") String path) {
        this.path = path;
   }
}
...

TestService service = new TestService("testValue");
```

Or set the value using [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html):

```java
TestService service = new TestService();
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "path", "somePath");
```